# Browser.msgBox not working onEdit in add-on google scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, google-apps-script-addon

I have a piece of code that runs on any edit in my google sheets that looks like this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
   Browser.msgBox("I pop up on Edit!");
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work when it's deployed and published on the Chrome Web Store as an Add-On... I have Browser.msgBox in other methods that don't involve edit triggers and they work fine.

I have tried using modal dialogs, ui alerts, notes, html pop-ups, and toast messages in replacement of Browser.msgBox but they all don't work in the edit trigger functions.

The only reasoning I could find is edit triggers are not compatible with pop-up boxes in Google Spreadsheets Add-ons. Could I get some light shed on this?

Comment: According to the [Apps Script Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/#triggers), an Add-on *can* use a simple trigger.  You might try changing the name from`onEdit` to something else, and "install" an "On Edit" trigger, and see if that makes any difference.

Comment: I found this issue reported to Google: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63950879
Star it in the issue tracker to give the issue momentum and to stay posted on updates.

Answer (score 1):

`onEdit()` will keep triggering when you're working in the sheet where you started your script (where it has been [bound](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#restrictions)), but if you try deploying it as a Sheet add-on, you'll need to explicitly install it as a trigger. Note that it must still be named `onEdit`, not `myEditingFunction`.

In order to test your triggering functionality, you must first deploy your Sheet add-on as some sort of restricted app (to bypass Google's review) and deploy it to a sheet outside your test sheets, otherwise your trigger installation will cause exceptions: `Exception: The Add-on attempted an action that is not permitted in Test as Add-on mode. To use this action, you must deploy the Add-on.`

Here's the way I was installing my `onEdit` triggers:

```
var sheetName = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getName();
var documentProperties = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties();
var editingFlag = documentProperties.getProperty(TRIGGER);
if (editingFlag == null) {
    try {
        trigger = ScriptApp.newTrigger("onEdit").forSpreadsheet(e.source).onEdit().create();
        documentProperties.setProperty(TRIGGER, "");
    } catch (e) {
        console.error("Caught exception on attempting to save trigger:" + e);
    }
} else {
    console.log("onEdit trigger is already listening for edits to sheet " + sheetName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample.

```
function onEdit(e){
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.alert("I pop up on Edit! " + e.value);
}
```

[image]

If you want to know about the detail, please check https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui

Comment: unfortunately these don't work either. i think ui calls in general are not working in the onEdit method

Comment: Try deploying it as an add-on. All of these methods don't work "onEdit" triggers when it's as an add-on

Comment: Its ok! i can't tell from the screenshot but we made our function, like yours, deployed it to as an Add-on in the store and it doesn't work in the deployed sheet. Our problem is that onEdits normally work but ui calls and browser messages don't work in onEdit when it is deployed as an add-on

Comment: In my browser (Chrome), it works fine under no triggers.

Comment: is it deployed as an add-on and installed into a sheet?